# How can I render a div that has its visibility:'hidden'? in PDFjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html2canvas, pdf.js

In one of the views in my React app, I have a button that takes 2 HTMLElements and display them in 2 pages in a PDF. My goal is for one of the elements to stay hidden.

The problem is that PDFjs does not render the hidden element. The same problem occurs when trying to set the element to `position:absolute` and to values like `-999999px`.

This is the piece of code responsible for capturing and saving:

```
const downloadIt = () => {
    const blackboard = document.getElementById('blackboard') as HTMLElement;
    const descriptionList = document.getElementById('elementDescriptions') as HTMLElement;
  
    const width = blackboard.offsetWidth;
    const height = blackboard.offsetHeight;
    const aspectRatio = width / height;
  
    html2canvas(blackboard).then((canvas) => {
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() * (1 / aspectRatio);
  
      pdf.text(comp.title, 8, 8);
      pdf.addImage(imageData, 'PNG', 15, 15, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 20, pdfHeight);
  
      pdf.addPage();
  
      // Add the descriptionList to the PDF
      if (descriptionList) {
        html2canvas(descriptionList).then((descCanvas) => {
          const descData = descCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          const descAspectRatio = descCanvas.width / descCanvas.height;
          const descWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 190; // Adjust the margins as needed
          const descHeight = descWidth * (1 / descAspectRatio);
  
          pdf.addImage(descData, 'PNG', 15, 15, descWidth, descHeight);
  
          pdf.save(`${comp.title}.pdf`);
        });
      } else {
        pdf.save(`${comp.title}.pdf`);
      }
    });
  };
```

The one I'd like to hide is the one called `descriptionList`, just a simple div with some Cards inside.

I've tried moving it out of the way, but it keeps giving me an error of corrupt PNG file passed to PDFjs.

How can I render `descriptionList` in my PDF?